# Cannot find module 'graceful-fs' happens with npm ci but not with npm install (with maven plugin)

Tags: reactjs, maven, npm, node-gyp, fsevents

We have some react projects that are built with `maven` because reasons.
Point is, we used to run a maven plug-in with `npm install`, and everything was fine with the world.

Lately we decided to improve our building process and use `npm ci` so all the versions would be fixed.

Since then, every time the project is built, we can see the following error:

```
[INFO] > fsevents@1.2.11 install /home/username/applications/react/magnificent-app-name/src/main/frontend/node_modules/fsevents
[INFO] > node-gyp rebuild
[INFO] 
[INFO] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
[INFO]     throw err;
[INFO]     ^
[INFO] 
[INFO] Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
[INFO]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
```

- If we run manually `npm install` in the project folder, no errors.
- If we run manually `npm ci` in the project folder, no errors.
- If we run `npm install` through the maven plug-in, no errors.
- If we run `npm ci` through the maven plug-in, the above error appears.

We also tried `npm ci --no-optionals` after reading some related github issues, but it didn't change anything.

We reinstalled npm.
We cleared the cache.
We did pretty much anything the internet said.
Still, `Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'`.

the maven plug-in definition, just in case:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
          <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                   <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
             </execution>
             <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                   <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <arguments>ci --no-optionals</arguments>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
             <execution>
                <id>npm build</id>
                <goals>
                   <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <arguments>run build -- --env.conf ${build.profile.id} --env.mvn</arguments>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
             <nodeVersion>${node.lts.version}</nodeVersion>
             <installDirectory>../node_installation</installDirectory>
             <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

We're using `node 10.15.3`.

Any ideas?